# Template compilation error: 'X' does not refer to a value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

I am getting the following error: `'ComponentManager' does not refer to a value` when compiling a subclass which inherits from this parent class:

```
template<typename ComponentManager>
class component_collection {
protected:
  int n_components;
  int n_versions;
  int first_blank;
  int last_used;
  std::vector<std::deque<shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>>>> entity_pointers;

public:
  component_collection(int n_c, int n_v) :
    n_components(n_c),
    n_versions(n_v),
    first_blank(0),
    last_used(0),
    entity_pointers(n_v, std::deque<shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>>>()) // <-- ERROR HERE
  {}

  ...

};
```

I am confused as to how I should initialise the `std::vector` with `n_v` empty `std::deque`s in the constructor.

The sub-class declares a similar `vector` of `deque`s and compiles / worked as expected (until I added the `vector<deque>` to the parent, that is):

```
template<typename ComponentManager>
class test_component_collection : public component_collection<ComponentManager> {
  std::vector<std::deque<int>> values;

public:
  test_component_collection(int n_c, int n_v) :
      component_collection<ComponentManager>(n_c, n_v),
      values(n_v, std::deque<int>()) // <-- NO ERROR HERE
  { }

  ...

};
```

So it seems this is something to do with this being a container of `std::shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>>`, but I don't see why that would be a problem (the `entity` header is included, takes a `<ComponentManager>` as you would expect, and a `ComponentManager` is provided when all these classes are used).

I am clearly missing something...

**Update**

Here's the code for `entity`:

```
template<typename ComponentManager>
class entity {
protected:
  ComponentManager & component_manager;

public:
  entity(ComponentManager & cm) : component_manager(cm) {}
  void initialise_components(shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>> sp) {}
};
```

Adding this at the top of `component_collection` seems to fix things (the compilation error at least, I've not thoroughly tested the results):

```
template<typename ComponentManager> using entity_ptr_deque = std::deque<shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>>>;
```

And then substituting `entity_ptr_deque<ComponentManager` in as appropriate. This aids readability, so I might leave it in anyway, but it doesn't help understand the error, especially as a minimal example builds fine (see comments).

**Update 2**

Using [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) from the comments, I found that my full class didn't compile, while the version edited by @VittorioRomeo did.

Switching from Clang to GCC on Wandbox (I'm using Clang locally) gave a very different error message:

```
declaration of 'auto component_collection<ComponentManager>::entity(int)' 
changes meaning of 'entity'
```

This is a method that was present before I added the `std::vector<std::deque<shared_ptr<entity<ComponentManager>>>> entity_pointers;` and associated constructor update. It of course masks the name `entity` in the class definition, hence the error. Clang's error message pointed somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Cannot reproduce [on a minimal example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yq2UDKDnjzWO8fYZ)

Comment: Try initializing `values` just with `values(n_v)`. Default initialization of the filling element is the default. Not an answer, but might give some more insight into what's happening.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the `entity` template or the header you're including?

Comment: I've added `entity`. I'm not entirely surprised the minimal example builds okay – I can't see why this wouldn't! Any thoughts where else to look? I haven't edited the pasted code at all, except to remove some member functions, but I don't see how they could affect this.

Comment: So defining the `deque<...` as a type alias seems to work. I'll update again above...

Comment: Yep @TheVee it does compile when I don't specify the type in the `deque` constructor. Doesn't quite get to the bottom of things, but thanks.

Comment: Let's see if there's more. Is it `std::shared_ptr` you're using or your own? I'm finding it suspicious that all the other STL entities have a fully qualified name but this is only used as a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Good thought, but I'm afraid it's just `std::shared_ptr`. Should've included the `using...` in the code, sorry.

Comment: Okay, so playing with my code vs what @VittorioRomeo helpfully put together (WandBox is incredibly useful, I've not seen it before), I've solved this. Turns out I was asking the wrong question really... What's the etiquette here? Should I post an answer / change the question / ask the 'correct' question separately?

Comment: @Leo Posting a self-answer to this is a good way out, and if you're interested in something else, ask another question. In the specific case of the resolution that you found I think that makes the question border on point 2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Clang compilation error `'X' does not refer to a value` can be misleading.

It means, at that point in the code, Clang is expecting a *value*, not a type. But the reason for that may be nothing to do with the nature of `X`.

It may be that whatever `X` is being passed *to* expects a value rather than a type, i.e. Clang does not think this is a template.

Specifically in this case: `template<typename ComponentManager> entity` has been masked by a method in the class – `auto entity(int)`. This changes the meaning of `entity`, causing an error at the site of the template specialisation, but *not* at the site of the method which is doing the masking.

GCC gives a much clearer error message in this instance, so it's worth trying a tool like [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/) to see what different compilers think is wrong with the code.