# template compiler error - does not refer to a value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The following code results in the compiler error 'Exception' does not refer to a value

```
    template <typename T>
    class A {
    public:
        virtual ~A() = 0;
        class Exception {
        };
    };

    template<typename T>
    inline A<T>::~A() {}

    template <typename T>
    class B : public A<T> {
    public:
        B() {}

        ~B() {}

        void foo() {
            throw B<T>::Exception();
        }
    };
    int main()
    {
        try {
            B<int> instB = B<int>();
            instB.foo();
        }
        catch(B<int>::Exception &e) {
            std::cout << "uh oh" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

but, if the type is explicitly specified into the throw, it works. It seems there is an issue in specifying the template type.

```
throw B<int>::Exception   // this works
```

From [Template compilation error: 'X' does not refer to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41222330/template-compilation-error-x-does-not-refer-to-a-value) this is an indicate that clang is expecting 'Exception' to be a value, not a type.

What is the proper way to thrown the template class Exception?

Comment: `throw typename B<T>::Exception();` See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: on gcc the compiler could fix the code itself :-): It throws the error message "note: say 'typename B<T>::Exception' if a type is meant". BTW: For clarity you should write A<T> because it is defined there... quite clear that B<T> derives from A<T> but it looks a bit strange...

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @Igor Tandetnik and @Klaus, the compiler needs to be told it's a type to disambiguate it.

```
void foo() { throw typename B<T>::Exception() }
```

or better

```
void foo() { throw typename A<T>::Exception() }
```